# View an image of size (4, 6, 6) with moving window of size (4, 3, 3)

Tags: numpy, scipy, keras, scikit-image

I wanted to view an image using moving window method, and calculate mean for each window:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.util import view_as_windows

image = np.ones((6,6)) # A single channel image
print (image.shape)
(6, 6)
result = view_as_windows(image, window_shape=(3,3), step=1)
print (result.shape)
```

(4, 4, 3, 3)

```
mean = np.mean(result, axis=(2,3))
print (mean.shape)    
(4, 4)
```

**But could not do it for 3D image.**

I wanted to view it with window size of (3, 3) using all channels (4).

```
image = np.ones((4, 6, 6)) #image with 4 channels
print (image.shape)
```

(4, 6, 6)

```
result = view_as_windows(image, window_shape=(4,3,3), step=1)
print (result.shape)
```

(1, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3)

```
mean = np.mean(result, axis=(4,5))
print (mean.shape)
```

(1, 4, 4, 4)

Comment: I can't see the question.

Comment: please see the bold sentence

Answer (score 1):

you have a trailing dimension here. discard it with :

```
view_as_windows(image, window_shape=(4,3,3)).squeeze()
```

then the dimensions will be :

```
(4, 6, 6)
(4, 4, 4, 3, 3)
(4, 4, 4)
```

Which I think it's what you want.

Comment: then, is it correct to calculate mean as, mean = np.mean(result, axis=(3,4))
print (mean.shape)?

Comment: The result shape is (4,4,4) : res[:,i,j] are the four means of window[i,j] for the four channels.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that your image is a 3-D array, `view_as_windows` yields a 6-D array. If you want to compute the mean of each window using vectorized code rather than through `for`loops you just need to pass the last three axes to NumPy's `mean` like this:

```
In [18]: img = np.ones((4, 6, 6))

In [19]: windows = view_as_windows(image, window_shape=(4, 3, 3), step=1)

In [20]: windows.shape
Out[20]: (1, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3)    

In [21]: avg = np.mean(windows, axis=(-1, -2, -3))

In [22]: avg.shape
Out[22]: (1, 4, 4)

In [23]: avg
Out[23]: 
array([[[1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1.]]])
```

Description of parameter `axis` from the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html):

> **axis : *None or int or tuple of ints, optional***
>
> > Axis or axes along which the means are computed. The default is to compute the mean of the flattened array.
> >     *New in version 1.7.0.*
> >     If this is a tuple of ints, a mean is performed over multiple axes, instead of a single axis or all the axes as before.

Comment: Is it `mean = np.mean(result, axis=(3,4))` after `squeeze()`?

Comment: The array with the means of the 3D windows is `avg`, which is also 3-dimensional (there is no need to squeeze).